Mechanism for the formation of cyclohexanone phenylhydrazone
I'm struggling to work out the mechanism of the reaction between cyclohexanone and phenylhydrazine as it has been a long time since I have last done organic chemistry. I'm very confused as to how the O in cyclohexanone is removed as well as the protons at the very end of phenylhydrazine. Could someone explain it?
Thank you.

It is not different from a normal imine (or normal hydrazone) formation mechanism. A google search for "hydrazone formation mechanism" should get you the results you want.

As @Sonder says phenylhydrazones form by the same mechanism as imines and hydrazones.
It is straightforward nucleophilic attack through the unsubstituted -NH2 followed by proton transfer and elimination of water (drawn as two steps) 
Picture sourced from here
